# Field value length validation with an Avro schema

Tags: database, validation, apache-nifi, avro

I'm using Apache NiFi to import CSV files into a MySQL database.

To validate the input I'm interested in using an [Avro schema](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.9.1/spec.html).

The problem is that I can't find in the spec anything about field value length (min, max or a range), and when I'm browsing nobody seems to ask about it.

What am I missing or getting wrong about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your input is CSV, you can use the ValidateCsv processor, it has its own DSL that allows more constraints than Avro does, such as `StrMinMax` and `LMinMax`.

Comment: Is it by design that Avro does not have length attributes for field declaration?

Comment: I believe so, I'm not aware of any field validation capabilities in Avro, the data type stuff is more about how to format incoming bytes rather than field validation.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, what you're asking for doesn't exist in Avro.

I know! I'm disappointed too. But the Apache folks are clear, "Avro is a data serialization system." https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AVRO/FAQ#FAQ-WhatisAvro?

Avro is an Apache project and it'd be good to catch them up to the data-engineering way... and for whatever reason, everything old is new again, and CSV's are *everywhere*. The argument has always been that static ("technical") validation is to ensure the deserialization of the object meets the minimum required to recreate the object. So data type and potential nulling is required.

Anything more than that has seemed like the realm of dynamic ("business") validation, e.g., is the length of the string less than or equal to 16 characters. Where I think Avro find itself -- especially with tools such as NiFi -- is at a crossroads of finding itself an integration/data-engineering tool. And what used to be "business" validation fluff, is now just good data-science.

@Josh hints about the hard "no", and fixed-length goes some way to help, but it was designed for binary, so the fixed-length is in bytes. If you're in unicode strings (e.g., Python), then your results should be uniform. But if one uses UTF-8 and a language that encodes strings as such, then byte count might not always track to character length.

In the spirit of work-arounds, if you're inclined to import first into Pandas, the Pandera project does a pretty good job of complex checks including lengths, min, max... actually all manner of statistics. This won't help much with NiFi natively.

What I do is use the "raw-ness" of Avro to push things to S3, and then a boatload of dataframe-enabled tools (I like Prefect and Dask myself), pick it up and make magic happen. Once done, the Python tools put it back to S3, where NiFi continues in its Avro-centred journey.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had a quick look at the docs and it seems that if you want a fixed length you need to use the [fixed data type](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#Fixed)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if I want to check a max value or a range, as it is possible to declare a field in a MySQL database?

Comment: Sorry not sure with that. It is possible that you are not able to do that?

Comment: It would have been cool to have a unified schema to validate everything in one step.